# Preventing form from going to action page also prevents data from being submitted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, preventdefault

I created a form that submits its input to a database via a PHP page, and it works great, except for that I can't get the below script to work.

The intention is to submit the form but without actually jumping to createaccount.php. However, when I use the jQuery script below it prevents the form data from being submitted at all.
This code is from a project from a few years ago, and back then it worked fine. It seems it also works for everyone else on StackOverflow, so... confusing.

If it helps, I'm using Chrome. And I also tried using e instead of event, and instead of preventDefault() I also tried stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation(), but these have the same results. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks for your time!

**HTML**

```
<form action="createaccount.php" method="post" id="form">
  Username:<input type="text" name="username">
  Password:<input type="password" name="password">
  Email:<input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").on('submit', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

Comment: send the data through ajax then?

Comment: I mean, duh... you're not allowing a form to submit, so it won't be submitted. AJAX is your most viable solution.

Comment: event.preventDefault() will stop the submission of your form through any or all ways, This is so that you can control the form and submit manually when you want. So as pointed out above, you should user ajax here to submit the form without navigation.

Comment: ...I forgot that Ajax existed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after event.preventDefault() add the following:

```
let form = document.getElementById('form')
form.submit()
```

and your form will be submitted

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault();` Stops the form from submitting.

after that line you could do an `$.ajax` request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").on('submit', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       url: 'createaccount.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: $("form").serialize(),
       success: function(data) {// do something if you want to give feedback}
     })
  });
})
```